# DataFX ListDataProvider returning [] and the ListView is not getting populated because ObservableList is always null

Tags: java, javafx, observablelist

ListDataProvider not reading from dataReader, while dataReader.get().any_func() is giving correct value, ObservableList is always null. DataFX JdbcSource class, JdbcConverter are used.

```
ObservableList<Product> getObservableList() throws IOException, 
SQLException
{
    JdbcConverter<Product> jdbcConverter = new JdbcConverter<Product>()
    {
        @Override
        public Product convertOneRow(ResultSet resultSet)
        {
            try
            {
                Product product = new Product();
                product.setProduct_name(resultSet.getString("PRODUCT_NAME"));
                product.setRemaining(resultSet.getString("QUANTITY_REM"));
                product.setSold(resultSet.getString("QUANTITY_SOLD"));
                return product;
            } catch (SQLException sqlException) {}
            return null;
        }
    };
/*Class.forName() method already there in Test class*/

Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","***","***");

/*dataReader.get().any_func() returning correct value*/

DataReader<Product> dataReader = new JdbcSource<>(connection,  jdbcConverter, "PRODUCTS", "PRODUCT_NAME", "QUANTITY_REM", "QUANTITY_SOLD");

/*listDataProvider.getData().getValue() is returning []*/

    ListDataProvider<Product> listDataProvider = new ListDataProvider<>(dataReader);        

/*listDataProvider.retreive() is returning null, i.e. ObservableList is empty*/

    Worker<ObservableList<Product>> retrieve = listDataProvider.retrieve();
    return retrieve.getValue();
}
```

And the Product class is

```
public class Product
{
    private String product_name;
    private String remaining;
    private String sold;

public String getProduct_name() {
    return product_name;
}

public void setProduct_name(String product_name) {
    this.product_name = product_name;
}

public String getRemaining() {
    return remaining;
}

public void setRemaining(String remaining) {
    this.remaining = remaining;
}

public String getSold() {
    return sold;
}

public void setSold(String sold) {
    this.sold = sold;
}
}
```

Comment: What do you need help with?

Comment: i am getting null observable list, and the listdataprovider.getdata().getvalue() is returning []

Comment: While the datareader.get().func_of_product_class() are returning the correct value from the resultset

Comment: But that looks like a JDBC issue. Provide a [mcve].

Comment: No, but the datareader is able to retrieve values from the database(i have tried printing those values on the console and they are getting printed correctly), the only problem is that listdataprovider is not retrieving value from datareader

Comment: If you could help me out, i would be very thankful to you!!!

Comment: What is the API for `ListDataProvider`?

Comment: DataFx, io.datafx

Comment: I'm not familiar with this library.

Comment: Ok, no problem!!!